# Connect to SQL Server (Postgresql database): what to use as hostname?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, visual-studio-code, ado.net

I'm trying to run SQL queries directly in VS Code but I cannot connect to a database. My problem is I don't know what hostname I should use.

When I try connection, I'm prompted with:

`hostname\instance` or `<server>.database.windows.net` or ADO.NET connection string

I tried using:

```
localhost:5432
```

but that doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Tag the database engine you actually use. Connection strings are very specific.

Comment: Is `localhost:5432` a server that exists and works when connecting 'natively'? What does "that doesn't work" mean; what error do you get exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Port 5432 suggests that you're trying to connect to a PostgreSQL server. Is this correct? You can't connect to a PostgreSQL server using an SQL Server driver as they're completely different protocols on the wire.

Answer (score -1):

get server name here :
[click here](https://blog.dbi-services.com/postgresql-get-my-database-server-name/)

```
SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(@"data source = Server__Name ; initial catalog = Database__Name; integrated security = true");
```

i hope it's help :))